# Редирект на главную в nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

Не удается сделать редирект на главную в nginx
Как сделать так, если в конце url вставлен index.php, вне зависимости от того, что перед index.php, редиректить на главную
т.е. ссылки вида

```
/watchh/a./asdww/index.php
/video/test/index.php
/index.php
```

должны редиректить на главную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите с `/Index.php` на `/` то так.

```
server {
    ...
    if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)index\.(?:php|html)") {
         return 301 $1;
    }
}
```

Либо так

```
location ~ ^/index.(html|php)$ {
  if ($request_uri ~ ^/index.(html|php)) {
    rewrite ^.*$ / permanent;
  }
}
```

Но тогда запросы на /index.html и /index.php будут давать 301 редирект на корень сайта, а сам сайт целиком будет работать как и прежде.